# Excel: Adding secondary axis for one data set, NOT series?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, axis

I created a bar graph of the mean abundances of fish from several families across 3 different sites.

One family is significantly more abundant than the others and so I am trying to put all of that families data on a secondary axis.

I've tried splitting the axis, but Excel will only let me put a series (in this case, which site I sampled from) on a secondary axis.

Is there any way I can put an entire data set on a new axis?

I have highlighted the data I want to put on a separate axis in orange and on the graph itself.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My proposal is to use logarithmic scale.
[image: Fish data]

Comment: That looks great! Thanks!

Comment: This is a better option than mine. I'll leave mine as it answers the question asked (in case someone finds a valid use case for it) but yours answers the question behind the question.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly move a single point to a secondary y-axis but you can fake it. First, though, a frame challenge: In your case, I'd recommend having two copies of the chart. One as shown above and one with the Y-Axis max manually set to 50 or so. Having one bar be on a different axis than the rest is likely to make it difficult for others to interpret the data in your chart.

---

That being said, you can setup an entirely new set of dummy data where everything is unchartable except the one point you want to move. In the example below, the `23` value was originally in cell C2 but that threw off my chart. I had 2 series (columns B & C) so I made 2 dummy series (columns D & E). I set every value in there to `=NA()` so it's be an error and not show up. You can probably also leave this blank but that sometimes shows up as `0` if you turn on values so I'm in the habit of using errors. Then, I moved the `23` value from C2 to E2 and extended the chart to include my two dummy series. I set both those dummy series to be on a secondary y-axis.

By default, they'll overlap the series on the primary axis. Since I have the same number of series on both vertical axes and since there is no data in the same position in both sets, it *looks* like just that one series is on a different axis. If you do this, you should at least turn on data labels for that weird series and possibly hide the values on the secondary y-axis like I did in the second picture. You'll probably also want to manually set the colors so it blends in with the rest.

[image: Example]

[image: Cleaned Up a bit]